# Textillate JS-JQuery animation is not the selected one (and always the same)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-textillate

I'm using [textillate.js](http://textillate.js.org/) to add animation to text. My html page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Textillate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">

    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tlt">
        Hello world
    </div>

    
    <script>
        $('.tlt').textillate({ in: { effect: 'bounceInDown' } });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

where the included scripts and css are taken from the following links:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jschr/textillate/master/jquery.textillate.js
- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/master/jquery.lettering.js
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/animate-css/animate.css/master/animate.min.css

The problem is that whatever I set as `effect` in the `in` object, the result is always the default textillate animation: the chars appear one after the other from left to right, and I can control the order of the appearing letters (e.g. setting `shuffle: true`, etc..), but not the animation type.

This is pretty much the example code that textillate offers on his github page, so I don't have any idea on where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to animate.css reference, i change it and it works. Hope it helps.

```js
    $('.tlt').textillate({ in: { effect: 'flipInY' } });

    $('.tlt2').textillate({ in: { effect: 'rollIn' } });

    $('.tlt3').textillate({"loop":true,"in":{"effect":"fadeInDownBig","shuffle":false,"reverse":false,"sync":false},"out":{"effect":"hinge","shuffle":true,"reverse":false,"sync":false}});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.compat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.6.1/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textillate/0.4.0/jquery.textillate.js"></script>

<div class="tlt">
        Hello world
</div>


<div class="tlt2" >
        Hello world
</div>


<div class="tlt3" >
        Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: I now actually copied the files used on the textillate website to be sure to use the same versions and it solved the problem, so maybe also you solution will work, I will try it in the future just to know it. Thanks for your answer